# asyncValidation on key strokes and throttled (not on blur)

Tags: redux-form

The redux-form `asyncValidation` is great but it only works on blur. Is it possible to make it happen during key presses, and throttled? So it runs only every 300ms and on final value?

Comment: Sounds like you mean trailing debouced, rather than throttled?

Comment: Oh yes sir that's correct, trailing debounced @bitstrider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible? The short answer is yes.

Is it tricky? Well, as you mentioned, theres the fact that the `asyncValidation` for `redux-form` option only works for the `onBlur` and you'd instead want it to work `onChange`.

So you could fork and add this feature into `redux-form`, so you can do this:

```js
@reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  asyncValidate: validator,
  //asyncBlurFields: ['username','password'],
  asyncChangeFields: ['username','password'], /* add this new option */
})
```

For the deboucing part, you'd want to somehow debounce the `onChange` handler rather than the validate function itself, which brings up another option...

`redux-form` exports its internal action creators which may be enough to hack it together. Particularly, there's the [`stopAsyncValidation`](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-stopasyncvalidation-form-string-errors-object-code-) action creator that lets you pass field-level async errors directly into a form. Pair that with the [`onChange`](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/field.md/#-code-onchange-event-newvalue-previousvalue-gt-void-code-optional-) prop for `Field`, and you actually have the right pieces to get it done like this:

[image: Edit Redux Form - Field-Level Validation]

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm, stopAsyncValidation } from 'redux-form'
import _debounce from 'lodash.debounce'

import renderField from './renderField'

@reduxForm({form: 'debouncedOnChangeValidation'})
class DebouncedOnChangeValidationForm extends React.Component {

  customValidate = () => {
    const { form, dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(stopAsyncValidation(form, { username: "thats wrong..." })) /* pass in async error directly! */
  }

  debounceValidate = _debounce(this.customValidate, 1000) /* decorate with debounce! */

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field name="username" type="text"
          component={renderField} label="Username"
          onChange={this.debounceValidate} /* bind validation to onChange! */
        />
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
          <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Additionally, to access the form values for performing validation, you'd need to use the [`getFormValues`](https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/selectors.md/#-code-getformvalues-formname-string-code-returns-code-state-gt-formvalues-object-code-) selector.

Of course this won't be as robust as a more built-in solution, but it may work well enough for some use cases.

Comment: Wow thank you sir for diving in so deep. Thank you very very much! I will also open a topic on redux-form with this awesome solution. Thank you! I posted it here - https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3613

Comment: Your welcome! I just happened to be familiar with some of the specifics

Comment: stopAsyncValidation didn't work for me, but I tried updateSyncErrors and it worked nice.